# angular Syntax Error: Token 'src' is an unexpected token

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

in [this plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UoXRO2hFYrdF68sPXb92), I am simply trying to create my own ng-include directive that just replaces the src attribute automatically with something else (add some extra params).

When the **'replace'** attribute on the directive is **'true'**, it breaks with the error above. If I set it to **'false'**, everything is ok but then I get an extra level of nesting in my DOM, which I'm trying to avoid...

The expression that fails is:

```
template: '<ng-include src="src | srcizer"></ng-include>'
```

Is there any way to use replace=true and still create this kind of ng-include alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
template: '<ng-include ng-src="src | srcizer"></ng-include>'
```

Comment: yes, this actually works. One note: I needed to set 'scope: false' because nested includes need access to any scope variables that are available....I updated the plunkr. Why ng-src fixes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you trying but seems you don't need to use ng-include since you can use `templateUrl` instead of `template` in directive. This allows to store angular templates like common html in html files.

Here is your updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ZUQ5mbIcBQDRQSTh7UJ?p=preview)

Pay attention to `templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html'` this update in your directive.

And now about `replace:true`. According to angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) its deprecated, so avoid using it.

> replace ([DEPRECATED!], will be removed in next major release - i.e. v2.0)

Comment: I'll wait and see, I'm sure 'replace' will have an alternative by then to avoid huge increase in nesting levels... I prefer using replace:true in the meantime

Comment: you can use replace in my updated plunker. just wanted to point that keeping teplates in separate html files with templateUrl in best practice and in your case ng-include is redundant

Comment: I looked at your plunkr, pls clarify: the name "mytemplate.html" seems to be hardcoded inside the directive instead of using the value from the 'src' attribute...

Comment: that's right. directive is behavior plus visualisation. having this in mind templateUrl is hardcoded

Comment: Thanks, however this does not satisfy the requirement.. After all, ng-include itself is a directive and its template isn't hardcoded.